# how can i reverse this disassembly code to c

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly

The disassembly code is this:

```
movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rax] ; 
add     ecx, 0FFFFFFFEh ; 
cmp     cl, 2
```

I guest the code is reversed like this:

```
if rax - 2 > 2  {
...
```

Is that right?
and why?

Comment: Almost, it just uses not the `rax` value itself, but it loads a byte from the RAM. So, it is more `if (somevar - 2 > 2) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

it'll wrap so you have four cases 0-1 , 2-3, 4 (=2) , >4
may be they've used OF check to distinct